# Получить массив не повторяющихся данных, после использования Regexp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Просьба помочь правильно получить массив не повторяющихся значений, после использования регулярного выражения.

Есть страница с такими данными. По сути это таблица с множеством столбцов, при чем строк может бть сколько угодно.

```
<tr>
<td data-sum="1" rowspan="3" class="ehb">
<h3><b><a title="Просмотреть" href="https://url909/mac?id=5******">5******</a></b></h3></td><td rowspan="3" class="ehb">
<div id="macs-mac_comment_5b9a3b3e9a9d2_5******" class="hjb">
<div></div>
<script id="script_macs-mac_comment_5b9a3b3e9a9d2_5******" class="Gc">decor('macs-mac_comment_5b9a3b3e9a9d2_5******', "mac");</script><a style="display: none;">сохранить</a>
</div>
</td>
<td align="center" rowspan="3" class="ehb"></td>
<td><big><a target="_blank" href="https://url909/tools?axid=105">105</a></big></td>
<td>Blanch</td>
<td align="right">1</td>
<td>231.1.1</td>
</tr>
...
```

Получаю необходимые числа из строк:

```
<a title="Просмотреть" href="https://url909/mac?id=5******">5******</a>
```

т.е. число 5******(оно всегда семизначное.) таким образом:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var httl = document.body.innerHTML;
var regex = /[5]+[0-9]{6}/g;
var itog = httl.match(regex); 
console.log(itog);
});
```

Необходимо записать все полученные числа в массив через точку без повторов. На данный момент они повторяются 5 раз.

5******.5******.5******.5******
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [объектом Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), который сохраняет только уникальные значения.

Для преобразования массива в строку с каким-либо разделителем стоит использовать метод [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var httl = '5123456512345659999995123456';
var regex = /[5]+[0-9]{6}/g;
var set = new Set();
httl.match(regex).forEach(v=>set.add(v));
var itog = Array.from(set).join('.');
console.log(itog);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Здорово. А случаем не подскажете, как записать их строкой через точку?

Comment: @user309309 точно, забыл про эту часть уговора. Дополнено.

Comment: Идеально. Спасибо, добрый человек. Бьюсь весь день, вроде бы лёгкое решение, но моих знаний маловато.

Comment: @user309309 пожалуйста, успехов вам ;)